# span, br и прочее внутри H1 - насколько это адекватно?

Tags: seo, html

Частенько встречаются сайты с логотипами, содержимое которых текст. Увеличенный красивый шрифт, например, два слова разными цветами и вот тебе лого :)

На главной это лого хочется сделать тэгом H1.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, насколько разумно использовать конструкции такого плана:

```
<h1>
    <a href="index.html">
        <span class="a">Что-нибудь</a>
        <br>
        <span class="b">консалтинг</span>
    </a>
</h1>
```

Comment: <br /> - так правильнее...

Comment: Это если xHTML. А в HTML5 и так вполне хорошо <br>. Ну а сейчас уже большинство используют не закрывающие тэги, так как HTML5 очень хорошо внедрился.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вполне разумно и адекватно. В любом случае, это лучше чем картинка. Даже если используешь картинку, все равно пиши текст и убирай его с помощью text-indent или с помощью jquery и поисковики тебя полюбят.

Удачи.

Comment: Ок :). Сбросили мои сомнения своей уверенностью. Насчет картинок и text-indent вкурсе. Только что обновил бойлерплейт. Там как раз выбранный из 100500 вариантов image replacement.